# Sending a Notification when a Bluetooth Headset connects

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to send a notification when a bluetooth headset connects to the device?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify if you talk about connected devices or paired devices

Your question is not very detailed so I cannot give an exact answer, but you can find all needed informations in the Android bluetooth documentation.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth#FindDevices

Read section "Find devices" and "Connect devices".

Greetings

Comment: I mean if i have paired headphones and i turn them on, they normally connect automatically to my android device. And how can I send a notification then when it connects. The headphones are already paired

Comment: Look into this:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40156699/which-correct-flag-of-autoconnect-in-connectgatt-of-ble