# ANDROID BLE How to autoconnect to peripheral from system like bluetooth headphones after bonding

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I’m interacting with my custom BLE periphy from my application and after some manipulations of the periphery offer a bond with me through the system window and I agree. In the future, I want the system itself to request a connection automatically as soon as my periphy get into its packet receiving radius (by analogy with the bluetooth column). And the question - do I need to do something in the application code after bonding to have this same auto-connect? Or the system itself will try to automatically connect to the periphery

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which correct flag of autoConnect in connectGatt of BLE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40156699/which-correct-flag-of-autoconnect-in-connectgatt-of-ble)

Comment: @Emil , unfortunately its works for case when I connect inside my app, I want the system itself to connect to a peripheral device when the opportunity arises (without the participation of my application)

Comment: post the code you have tried

Answer (score 1):

The system never connects to BLE devices by itself. You need to have an app that initiates the connection.

However if the BLE device implements a profile that the system has built-in support for, like HID, then the system will automatically initiate a connection to that device (without any app). But the profile for that device must be paired and enabled through the system's Bluetooth settings.

Comment: that is, I will create a bond with an HID device, will the smartphone automatically connect if bluetooth is on?

Comment: Only if the user does it through the Bluetooth settings. Not if you just call createBond from your application.