Android Foreground Service Execution during Doze Mode
I've read up on Doze mode, but the documentation is somewhat sparse. I have a foreground service, which executes a Looper every 30 seconds.
In Doze mode this execution does only happen during the maintenance windows.
Is there any method to execute (the very lightweight) code in the foreground service? It only checks if a BLE connection is still there and reconnects when not.
The BLE connection is held during doze mode. Only the reconnection, which I realized trough the periodic check does not, since the coroutine in the foreground service is not called during doze mode.

What you are describing would require your process to constantly be using 1+ CPU cores. This will result in significant power drain, which is why Doze mode was introduced in the first place. Have you tried manually opting your app out of battery optimization in the Settings app?

Yeah, this helps with app-standby, but unfortunately not with doze mode. Since its BLE, I cannot use other methods to reestablish BLE connection.

If the goal is to maintain BLE connectivity, having a Foreground Service as well as creating the BluetoothGatt object with autoConnect=true should typically be sufficient. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40187086/556495.
